# Time complexity for function converting list to set and vice versa

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-complexity, big-o

I am converting a list to set and back to list. I know that `set(list)` takes O(n) time, but I am converting it back to list in same line `list(set(list))`. Since both these operations take O(n) time, would the time complexity be O(n^2) now?

Logic 1:

```
final = list(set(list1)-set(list2))
```

Logic 2:

```
s = set(list1)-set(list2)
final = list(s)
```

Do both these implementations have different time complexities, and if they do which of them is more efficient?

Comment: O(n) + O(n) is O(n). And your two versions are essentially identical.

Comment: As has been pointed out, these two `n` are added not multiplied. On a side note the back conversion is bound by the unique elements in `list1` which may be fix or may increase proportionally with its length (or any other function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One set conversion is unnecessary, as `set.difference` works with any iterable as it should:

```
final = list(set(list1).difference(list2))
```

But the asymptotic time and space complexity of the whole thing is still `O(m+n)` (the sizes of the two lists).

Answer (score 1):

In both versions you are doing:

- convert a list to a set
- convert another list to a set
- subtract the two sets
- convert the resultant set to a list

Each of those is O(n), where n is a bound on the size of both your starting lists.

That's O(n) four times, which makes it overall O(n).

Your two versions are essentially identical.

Answer (score 1):

Your two versions are identical, as from `dis`:

```
>>> dis.dis("list(set(list1) - set(list2))")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (list)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (set)
              4 LOAD_NAME                2 (list1)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              8 LOAD_NAME                1 (set)
             10 LOAD_NAME                3 (list2)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             14 BINARY_SUBTRACT
             16 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             18 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis("s = set(list1) - set(list2);list(s)")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (set)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (list1)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 LOAD_NAME                0 (set)
              8 LOAD_NAME                2 (list2)
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 BINARY_SUBTRACT
             14 STORE_NAME               3 (s)
             16 LOAD_NAME                4 (list)
             18 LOAD_NAME                3 (s)
             20 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             22 POP_TOP
             24 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             26 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

The only difference between these two is that the second one stores it to a variable `s`, so it has to `LOAD_NAME` the name `s`. And in the first code the `list` is called first, but in the second one get's called later.

But in @user2390182's answer, instead of a second loaded `set` `LOAD_NAME`, it loads the function name `difference` instead, which IMO is the most efficient one here:

```
>>> dis.dis("list(set(list1).difference(list2))")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (list)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (set)
              4 LOAD_NAME                2 (list1)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              8 LOAD_METHOD              3 (difference)
             10 LOAD_NAME                4 (list2)
             12 CALL_METHOD              1
             14 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             16 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```